# How do I replace a variable with its file name for a batch of csv files in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have 725 csv files with the following name `Pheno_Threshold1:725.csv`.  I need to replace the variable `SCORE` in each of them with their respective file name without the .csv extension.

```
V1          V2      V3        V4       V5       V6
FID         IID     PHENO     CNT      CNT2     **SCORE**
PT-CDGH     1       1         8512     40       -0.000371501
```

My desired result should be like this:

```
V1          V2      V3        V4       V5       V6
FID         IID     PHENO     CNT      CNT2     Pheno_Threshold1:725
PT-CDGH     1       1         8512     40       -0.000371501
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your working directory is the folder where the files reside (or you can change it with `setwd` or in the code below)

```
for (i in 1:725){
 file <- read.csv(paste0("Pheno_Threshold",i,".csv"),header=TRUE)
 names(file)[6] <- paste0("Pheno_Threshold",i)
 write.csv(file,paste0("Pheno_Threshold",i,".csv"),row.names=FALSE) 
}
```

You may want to output the new csv into another folder to avoid overwriting.

Comment: Thank you! This is it :). I just need the file name on [2,6], but when I add the 2 to the [], it sends me this error "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix". What is happening here?

Comment: I just added skip = 1, and it did it. Thanks so much!